# How to break out of a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value, return-type

Here is the piece of code, note I have commented of what I would like to achieve in the code

```
const extraHot = () => {
   if (hot === "h") {
      return `extra hot`
   }
// otherwise, do nothing, don't return anything
// (not even an empty string or undefined object)
// I want to break here
}

if (givenAmount >= dict){
// I would like to return "Drink maker makes 1 extra hot sugar and 1 stick"
    return `Drink maker makes 1 ${extraHot()} sugar and 1 stick`
}
```

The following code will return "undefined" between "makes" and "sugar"

```
const extraHot = () => {
   if (hot === "h") {
      return `extra hot`
   }
   return
}
```

The following code will return a space between "makes" and "sugar"

```
const extraHot = () => {
   if (hot === "h") {
      return `extra hot`
   }
   return ""
}
```

Comment: Every function in JS returns something. If no explicit `return` is given or there is a `return` statement with nothing following it, then you get `undefined`.

Comment: You can't not return anything from a JavaScript function, the default `return;`, which implicitly returns `undefined`, is as close as you'll get.

Comment: OK, after re-reading the question, this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The problem isn't that you have to return "nothing" from a function but how to make that template literal output a correct string. Note that even if you *could* return "nothing" (and an empty string is the closest you can get here), then the output string is still wrong. You need to return *negative one space* for this to work.

Comment: If you "break out of a function", you'd go back to the place were it was called without returning anything. `undefined` is "not anything".

Comment: @VLAZ thank you, I should have phrased my question more clearly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not what the function returns if `hot !== "h"`, but how you write your template string. In case of if evaluates to true, return `' extra hot '`, and write the template string like

`Drink maker makes 1${extraHot()}sugar and 1 stick`

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see it! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the space between *makes* and *sugar* is because you have one space after `makes` and another one in front of `sugar`. To prevent this you would have to change the extra hot function to:

```
const extraHot = () => {
   if (hot === "h") {
      return "extra hot " # Note the space after hot
   }
   return ""
}
```

And use it later with:

```
if (givenAmount >= dict){
    return `Drink maker makes 1 ${extraHot()}sugar and 1 stick`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize functions for returning a string to return an empty string and if some result take an extra space in front of the string or at the end and keep this style.

This approach allowes to chain conditions and get no extra space, if the condition is wrong.

In this case take

```
const extraHot = () => hot === "h" ? ' extra hot' : '';
```

and

```
if (givenAmount >= dict) return `Drink maker makes 1${extraHot()} sugar and 1 stick`;
```

The result is either

```
Drink maker makes 1 sugar and 1 stick
```

or

```
Drink maker makes 1 extra hot sugar and 1 stick
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```